# adding event listner to checkbox ticked-unticked image

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

There is a CRM website afocourse not built by me and therefore I cannot change the code.
Though they have provided us an option called as Web applet through which we can write hml javascript etc and therfore omodify the code.
Now my problem is a checkbox.

Intially i thought they must have used HTML checkbox field but it seems they its just an image.

My Requirement: When the check-box is ticked, user should be prompted with YES\NO prompt box.
The code snippet as it appears on the page is :

When the checkbook is checked(this is the path on the webpage)

```
<td class="fv fvu" style="padding-left: 6px; cursor: default;" id="A0.R0.ZBool_1"><img src="../024.008.000/base/themes/contemporary/images/ckb_checked.gif" border="0"></td>
```

When the checkbox is unchked, this is the path on the webpage

```
<td class="fv fvu" style="padding-left: 6px; cursor: default;" id="A0.R0.ZBool_1"><img src="../024.008.000/base/themes/contemporary/images/ckb_unchecked.gif" border="0"></td>
```

The gif at the end of path is changing ...How should I do this...any code, sample even will help me a lot..

Comment: Personally, I like to use hidden checkboxes - they're power-user friendly! [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5yNJF/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one :-

```
$(".fv").click(function(){
    // check whether this element has child with image
    var imageItem = $(this).find("img");
    if(imageItem) // for checking whether it has image children or not
    {
       var imgSrc = $(imageItem).attr("src");
       if(imgSrc && imgSrc == "../024.008.000/base/themes/contemporary/images/ckb_checked.gif")
       {
           alert("Yes/No");
           // play here
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Please try this

```
(function(){
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.fvu img').click(function(){
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var regexp = new RegExp("_checked.gif");

            if(regexp.test(src)){
                var answer = confirm_box();

                if(answer){
                    alert('You said :: Yes')
                }

                else{
                    alert('You said :: Nope')
                }
            }           
        })


    })

    function confirm_box(){
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to continue...");
    }
})(jQuery)
```